# Calling an html page in a java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have this auto-generated java servlet and tomcat 6 running. I want to call my HTML file in the java servlet so I can see my page on localhost. I found out that I need to be using `requestdispatcher` but I can't seem to get it work using the below code:

```
package com.captiveportal;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Demo
 */
public class Demo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Demo() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("captiveportal.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("captiveportal.html");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error you have?

Comment: The page doesn't show up when I go to localhost:8080 I just get a 404. Do  I need to put my html file in a specific location maybe? At the moment it is just located in a folder on my desktop.

Comment: Can you show us the web.xml and the path of captiveportal.html

Answer (score 0):

Are u giving correct path of the html page?? Try using the below path - http::/host:port/rootApp/../yourHtml